# DNN 9.01.01 Export/Import Stuck on Submitted Status

Tags: azure, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

We are transitioning to DNN 9.01.01 build, but it seems that the import/export feature is not working properly.  I submitted an import but it has been sitting on submitted status for the last 8 hours.

Is this a known issue or is there configuration on the server that preventing the import/export to work?

Our instance is installed on Azure

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We contacted support as well and looks like it was an issue with installing DNN as Azure webapps.

We had to delete all the unused server and set the task to run on the current active server and start the import/export feature manually on the scheduler tab.

Comment: I had the same issue but not in an Azure setup, just a traditional IIS hosting of DNN.

Answer (score 2):

This thread hasn't been touched in a long time but I dug around and found the problem. I fixed this problem by directly editing the DNN database. I'm on version 9.4 although, I'm sure this would work with any version as this issue is apparently caused some wonky code in the Azure AppService deployment packages.

To resolve, I just had to manually edit the dbo.Schedule table. I use Azure Data Studio because I'm on a Mac but SSMS or any other manager will work as well. I'm sure you can even use the DNN built-in editor although I'm not very familiar with it.

While digging through the dependencies I noticed that unlike the non-operational Export/Import job, all the working jobs had a NULL value in the "Server" field whereas the Export/Import job had the Azure server name written to it. I manually changed the value of this field to NULL and the Site Import job that had been perpetually spinning, started immediately.

Also, for posterity, you will want to make sure you don't have 15 different import jobs queued up before you do this because they will ALL begin processing once you commit the new value to the DB. If it took you a few times to figure out they were spinning you will probably want to go to the scheduler and delete anything you don't want to run prior to the DB edit.

Hope this helps save someone else some time. Cheers!

Comment: You can accomplish the same goal by going into the Persona bar Scheduler section. In the Scheduler tab, find the offending job, edit it, and remove the server name, then click Update and all good.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, when checking the other task scheduled for execution I noticed the server field was empty while on the import/export there were comma separated inputs. When I cleared the import/export field the task ran correctly.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe they left out coded for this I'm DNN 9. I tried using it for a customer and it was useless.

I inquired and got a response that said it was an oversight.

Comment: Thanks, we contacted support as well and looks like it was an issue with installing DNN as Azure webapps.  We had to delete all the unused server and set the process to run on the current active process and start the import/export feature manually on the scheduler tab.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the possible issues that can cause this, We had renamed our server and the scheduled task still had the original name of the server. Once we changed the name to the new one under the task, it started running as scheduled.

HTH

Dave